# The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open. (error)

Tags: c#, database, connection

The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open. (error)
That is my error.
Here is a picture from it:
http://gyazo.com/182a9c61189d15aa0dff79674c4cf871
Yes i made a connectionstring but it is in my public partial class.

if anyone is wordering what language im using: it is Dutch :)

This is my code:

```
private void btnOpslaanwerknemergegevens_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlCommand scmdNaam, scmdVoornaam, scmdStraat, scmdHuisnr, scmdPostcode, scmdGemeente, scmdBurgerlijkestand, scmdGeboorte_datum, scmdKinderen_ten_laste, scmdAfdeling, scmdIn_dienst_sinds, scmdGewest, scmdMinder_valide, scmdMinder_valide_partner, scmdMinder_valide_kinderen, scmdInkomen_partner, scmdEmail, scmdTel_nr, scmdGsm_nr;

        // new sqlcommands
        scmdNaam = new SqlCommand();
        scmdVoornaam = new SqlCommand();
        scmdStraat = new SqlCommand();
        scmdHuisnr = new SqlCommand();
        scmdPostcode = new SqlCommand();
        scmdGemeente = new SqlCommand();
        scmdBurgerlijkestand = new SqlCommand();
        scmdGeboorte_datum = new SqlCommand();
        scmdKinderen_ten_laste = new SqlCommand();
        scmdAfdeling = new SqlCommand();
        scmdIn_dienst_sinds = new SqlCommand();
        scmdGewest = new SqlCommand();
        scmdMinder_valide = new SqlCommand();
        scmdMinder_valide_kinderen = new SqlCommand();
        scmdMinder_valide_partner = new SqlCommand();
        scmdInkomen_partner = new SqlCommand();
        scmdEmail = new SqlCommand();
        scmdTel_nr = new SqlCommand();
        scmdGsm_nr = new SqlCommand();

        //sqlcommand.connections
        scmdNaam.Connection = loonberekening;
        scmdVoornaam.Connection = loonberekening;
        scmdStraat.Connection = loonberekening;
        scmdHuisnr.Connection = loonberekening;
        scmdPostcode.Connection = loonberekening;
        scmdGemeente.Connection = loonberekening;
        scmdBurgerlijkestand.Connection = loonberekening;
        scmdGeboorte_datum.Connection = loonberekening;
        scmdKinderen_ten_laste.Connection = loonberekening;
        scmdAfdeling.Connection = loonberekening;
        scmdIn_dienst_sinds.Connection = loonberekening;
        scmdGewest.Connection = loonberekening;
        scmdMinder_valide.Connection = loonberekening;
        scmdMinder_valide_kinderen.Connection = loonberekening;
        scmdMinder_valide_partner.Connection = loonberekening;
        scmdInkomen_partner.Connection = loonberekening;
        scmdEmail.Connection = loonberekening;
        scmdTel_nr.Connection = loonberekening;
        scmdTel_nr.Connection = loonberekening;

        scmdNaam.CommandText = "UPDATE werknemer SET naam = \'" + txtNaam.Text + "\' WHERE ID = \'" + _id + "\'";
        scmdVoornaam.CommandText = "UPDATE werknemer SET voornaam = \'" + txtVoornaam.Text + "\' WHERE ID = \'" + _id + "\'";
        scmdStraat.CommandText = "UPDATE werknemer SET straat = \'" + txtStraat.Text + "\' WHERE ID = \'" + _id + "\'";
        scmdHuisnr.CommandText = "UPDATE werknemer SET huisnr = \'" + txtStraatnr.Text + "\' WHERE ID = \'" + _id + "\'";
        scmdPostcode.CommandText = "UPDATE werknemer SET postcode = \'" + txtPostcode.Text + "\' WHERE ID = \'" + _id + "\'";
        scmdGemeente.CommandText = "UPDATE werknemer SET gemeente = \'" + txtGemeente.Text + "\' WHERE ID = \'" + _id + "\'";
        scmdBurgerlijkestand.CommandText = "UPDATE werknemer SET burgerlijkestand = \'" + cbxStand.Text + "\' WHERE ID = \'" + _id + "\'";
        scmdGeboorte_datum.CommandText = "UPDATE werknemer SET geboorte_datum = \'" + txtGeboortedatum.Text + "\' WHERE ID = \'" + _id + "\'";
        scmdKinderen_ten_laste.CommandText = "UPDATE werknemer SET kinderen_ten_laste = \'" + txtKinderentenlaste.Text + "\' WHERE ID = \'" + _id + "\'";
        scmdAfdeling.CommandText = "UPDATE werknemer SET afdeling = \'" + txtAfdeling.Text + "\' WHERE ID = \'" + _id + "\'";
        scmdIn_dienst_sinds.CommandText = "UPDATE werknemer SET in_dienst_sinds = \'" + txtIndien.Text + "\' WHERE ID = \'" + _id + "\'";
        scmdGewest.CommandText = "UPDATE werknemer SET Gewest = \'" + cbxGewest.Text + "\' WHERE ID = \'" + _id + "\'";
        scmdMinder_valide.CommandText = "UPDATE werknemer SET minder_valide= \'" + cbxValide.Text + "\' WHERE ID = \'" + _id + "\'";
        scmdMinder_valide_kinderen.CommandText = "UPDATE werknemer SET minder_valide_kinderen = \'" + txtHoeveelvalidekinderen.Text + "\' WHERE ID = \'" + _id + "\'";
        scmdMinder_valide_partner.CommandText = "UPDATE werknemer SET minder_valide_partner = \'" + cbxPartner.Text + "\' WHERE ID = \'" + _id + "\'";
        scmdInkomen_partner.CommandText = "UPDATE werknemer SET inkomen_partner = \'" + txtInkomenpartner.Text + "\' WHERE ID = \'" + _id + "\'";
        scmdEmail.CommandText = "UPDATE werknemer SET [e-mail] = \'" + txtEmail.Text + "\' WHERE ID = \'" + _id + "\'";
        scmdTel_nr.CommandText = "UPDATE werknemer SET tel_nr = \'" + txtTelefoonnr.Text + "\' WHERE ID = \'" + _id + "\'";
        scmdGsm_nr.CommandText = "UPDATE werknemer SET gsm_nr = \'" + txtGsmNr.Text + "\' WHERE ID = \'" + _id + "\'";




        loonberekening.Open();
        txtNaam.Text = Convert.ToString(scmdNaam.ExecuteScalar());
        txtVoornaam.Text = Convert.ToString(scmdVoornaam.ExecuteScalar());
        txtStraat.Text = Convert.ToString(scmdStraat.ExecuteScalar());
        txtStraatnr.Text = Convert.ToString(scmdHuisnr.ExecuteScalar());
        txtPostcode.Text = Convert.ToString(scmdPostcode.ExecuteScalar());
        txtGemeente.Text = Convert.ToString(scmdGemeente.ExecuteScalar());
        cbxStand.Text = Convert.ToString(scmdBurgerlijkestand.ExecuteScalar());
        txtGeboortedatum.Text = Convert.ToString(scmdGeboorte_datum.ExecuteScalar());
        txtKinderentenlaste.Text = Convert.ToString(scmdKinderen_ten_laste.ExecuteScalar());
        txtAfdeling.Text = Convert.ToString(scmdAfdeling.ExecuteScalar());
        txtIndien.Text = Convert.ToString(scmdIn_dienst_sinds.ExecuteScalar());
        cbxGewest.Text = Convert.ToString(scmdGewest.ExecuteScalar());
        cbxValide.Text = Convert.ToString(scmdMinder_valide.ExecuteScalar());
        txtHoeveelvalidekinderen.Text = Convert.ToString(scmdMinder_valide_kinderen.ExecuteScalar());
        cbxPartner.Text = Convert.ToString(scmdMinder_valide_partner.ExecuteScalar());
        txtInkomenpartner.Text = Convert.ToString(scmdEmail.ExecuteScalar());
        txtEmail.Text = Convert.ToString(scmdEmail.ExecuteScalar());
        txtTelefoonnr.Text = Convert.ToString(scmdTel_nr.ExecuteScalar());
        txtGsmNr.Text = Convert.ToString(scmdGsm_nr.ExecuteScalar());
        loonberekening.Close();
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). And in the grand scheme of things, why are you defining all those update queries? It's highly wasteful to run multiple queries when you could run just one. `update foo set field=value, field=value, field=value .... where id=$id` is far more efficient.

Comment: is there a reason why you are creating all the sqlcommand objects in a single method.. break it out into smaller individual functions.. also don't ask what you can do.. have you thought about using the debugger..? if so you will quickly see where you need to make your modifications / changes..also I would recommend putting that code into a stored procedure and depending on the order of events in regards to your process flow, draw it out on paper and start creating separate methods /functions for each of the sql commands your'e trying to execute.. this is very sloppy at best..

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is not the correct one. An UPDATE command could update more than one field at time. So you need to change the UPDATE command text to something like this

Note: This is pseudocode, you need to fill the points...

```
private void btnOpslaanwerknemergegevens_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cmdText = @"UPDATE werknemer 
                       SET naam = @nam, 
                       voornaam = @voornaam,
                       .... continue with other fields 
                       .... and finish with
                       WHERE ID = @id";
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(.... connectionstring ....))
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con))
    {
         con.Open();
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@naam", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtNaam.Text; 
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@vornaam", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtVoornaam.Text; 
         ... continue adding a parameter for every field value .....    
         ... and finally call ...
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
```

}

In this pseudocode, the connection is not a global object, but it is created locally using the Using Statement that will close and dispose the Connection also in case of exceptions. Then the command text is built using parameters placeholders (the @xxxx) and finally just one single command is executed after filling the parameter collection with the values to pass to your database engine to replace the placeholders.

Comment: that's far better :=)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (loonberekening.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    loonberekening.Open();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but im getting this error then: http://gyazo.com/c18a76bf3fb092b2dbb81dd6c1b136e4 (picture)

Comment: Thanks a lot but where do i need to put it in? under loonberekening.close();? or do i need to remove loonberekening.open&close (sorry im very bad at this)

Comment: You replace the Open statement with those 3 lines :=)
You can not open an already open connection, so you can check the state of the connection and open it only if needed...

Comment: so like this? http://gyazo.com/7810321ae40d31a7f0e173646064bbc4 because im still getting the same error: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open. (error) ;D

Comment: damn.. so you connection is in another state.. .then closed or opened :=)

Comment: actually here is my FULL code. as you can see there are 2 opens & 2 closes, 1 in my btn & 1 in form load, here is my code :P Here are some pictures: 1. http://gyazo.com/e910ec0f5a2b79eec79c661a67d92914 , 2. http://gyazo.com/9746effa31708db368cdfe4dee19350e , 3. http://gyazo.com/c4925da64a80044eeb1581fd9b4b7d65 , 4.http://gyazo.com/23ee7affafa125af9acabdc3a229c563 5. http://gyazo.com/79e64cb240988af3aaf377dce1f8d685 6. http://gyazo.com/e910ec0f5a2b79eec79c661a67d92914  this is in the correct order :P

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like loonberekening was opened outside of btnOpslaanwerknemergegevens_Click and never closed.  It's hard to tell without more of your code, but I'm guessing you have loonberekening has a shared variable since btnOpslaanwerknemergegevens_Click doesn't seem to be creating it.  Maybe it is already opened before btnOpslaanwerknemergegevens_Click is called.  I suggest creating a new connection within btnOpslaanwerknemergegevens_Click.